# Replace an empty group name with actual name in openLDAP

Tags: replace, null, ldap, openldap, groupname

I have an empty group got created in my openLDAP server. Somehow i figured it out that there is a group with empty name with this command ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -x -b "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" memberOf=cn=\00,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com and serach result is

LDAPv3

base <ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree

filter: memberOf=cn=00,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

requesting: ALL
search result

search: 2
result: 0 Success

numResponses: 1

My question is how do I replace this group with empty/null name with actual name(eg. abcd).